# Products dissapeared from website after reindexing

Tags: magento2

I have a plugin which imports products from an XML file to Magento 2, and after finally getting it to work, it wasn't displaying images of the products on the site (it does in the backend though). So I ran a re-index and now it isn't displaying any products at all (they are still in the backend).

The products are set to visible and have enough stock. These are the settings for the product:
[image: Example product settings]

This only started to happen after re-indexing. Any clues on what this could be?